# Select category and child category with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, select, undefined, typeof

I have a problem in my code which is a jQuery issue but I can't figure out what it is. When I upload a product and try to select the parent category my browser freezes (like it's consuming a lot of memory). Also the child select menu is showing the parent titles. When I edit a product the parent and the child is showing correctly and in the child select option menu I can make changes but when I try this with the parent select it freezes my browser again...

When I remove " selected: selected " from the get_child_options, the selection is working properly, but when I edit a product the previously selected child category is missing.

This is the product upload section where the user can select the category:

```
 <p class="admin-estate-add-section-input">
   Parent category
 </p>
 <select class="admin-estate" name="parent" id="parent">
 <option value=""<?=(($parent == '')?' selected':'')?>></option>
 <?php while($p = mysqli_fetch_assoc($parentQuery)): ?>
 <option value="<?=$p['id'];?>"<?=(($parent == $p['id'])?' selected':'')?>><?=$p['category'];?></option>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 </select>
 <br>
 <br>
 <p class="admin-estate-add-section-input">
    Child category
 </p>
 <select class="admin-estate" name="child" id="child"></select>
 <br>
 <br>
```

This is the jQuery function that calls the child_categories.php file

```
    <script>
 function get_child_options(selected){
 if(typeof selected === 'undefined'){
 var selected = '';
 }
 var parentID = jQuery('#parent').val();
 jQuery.ajax({
 url: '/tartalomkezelo/admin/parsers/child_categories.php',
 type: 'POST',
 data: {parentID : parentID, selected: selected},
 success: function(data){
 jQuery('#child').html(data);
 },
 error: function(){alert("Something went wrong! Can't select category.")},
 });

 }

 jQuery('select[name="parent"]').change(get_child_options);

 </script>
```

This is the child_categories.php file:

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tartalomkezelo/core/init.php';
$parentID = (int)$_POST['parentID'];
$selected = sanitize($_POST['selected']);
$childQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = '$parentID' ORDER BY category");
ob_start(); ?>
<option value=""></option>
 <?php while($child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($childQuery)): ?>
 <option value="<?=$child['id'];?>"<?=(($selected == $child['id'])?' selected':'');?>><?=$child['category'];?></option>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php echo ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

And then the script for the product upload file:

```
<script>
 jQuery('document').ready(function(){
 get_child_options('<?=$category;?>');
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I am not strong in PHP, but my guess that it is one of 'while' parts making it freeze. Try to replace them with some dummy result/data.

Comment: I don't think I follow you. With foreach for example?

Comment: I mean that it probably go into infinite or very long loop in one of those 'while' calls. So put some additional parameter like so:

while(*your params* &&counter<10)
{
   *your code*
   counter++;
}

so just make sure that it will go out of that loop.